# What is the equivalent of executing multiple instance methods in functional programming in JS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming

Suppose I have a class in JS with Typescript like this:

```js
type Command = 'F' | 'B' // Forwards, Backwards

class Car {
  private x: number
  private y: number

  constructor(x: number, y: number) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
  }

  private reportPosition() {
    return `(${this.x}, ${this.y})`
  }

  private move(command: Command) {
    if (command === 'F') this.y++
    if (command === 'B') this.y--
  }

  execute(command: Command) {
    this.move(command)
    return this.reportPosition()
  }
}
```

When I create a Car instance and execute the `execute` method, two things happen:

- The internal state of the instance (x, y) is updated.
- The `execute` function returns a string.

Now I want to write the same thing in a more FP way, making the functions pure, but I stumble at the `execute` function.
My approach is this:

```js
type Command = 'F' | 'B'

type Car = {
  x: number
  y: number
}

function createCar(x: number, y: number): Car {
  return { x, y }
}

function reportPosition(car: Car) {
  return `$({car.x}, ${car.y})`
}

function move(car: Car, command: Command) {
  if (command === 'F') return createCar(car.x + 1, car.y)
  if (command === 'B') return createCar(car.x - 1, car.y)
  return car
}


function execute(car: Car, command: Command) {
  const newCar = move(car, command)
  const msg = reportPosition(newCar)
  
  return [newCar, msg]
}
```

My questions are the following:

1. Since `execute` does two things at once, I feel I am forced to return two values from it in the function. But this feels wrong.
   Is this "valid" functional programming? Or would I never create such a function in the FP world and just call each of the functions inside (`move`, `reportPosition`) separately.
2. What if the `move` function also had to return the information on whether the car has crashed after its move? Would I also have to return two values from that modified function: the new car instance and a boolean (indicating a crash)?
3. Also, I used the `createCar` function within the `move` function, which is technically not allowed for pure functions, correct?
   What would be the best way to fix that? Pass the `createCar` function as an argument to `move`?

Thanks!

Comment: There are some FP libraries for the js/ts ecosystem that attempt to model functors/monads/semigroups/etc. See fp-ts for instance.

Comment: Really, I wouldn't even have an `execute` function here. `move` returns an altered state, then the caller can call `reportPosition` on the new state if they want to.

Comment: And for 3, I don't know why that wouldn't be allowed for FP. Data goes in, data goes out. It isn't carrying out side effects.

Comment: I think he has some misconceptions on what "pure" means in FP. It seems based on his questions that he believes he's not allowed to call other functions, and by doing so would make it impure, which is not the case.

Comment: 1) You can return whatever you want as long as you return something and as long as you return the same output for the same input. 3) You can call a function within another one as long as it is a pure function, If the callee is impure, the caller gets impure as well.

Comment: FYI your `execute` function looks a lot like what happens with a `State` monad. A state monad takes a state and returns an updated state and another value. This is what your execute does: takes a car state, returns a new car state and also a stringified version of the car's position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Doing two things at once doesn't necessarily make a function invalid functional programming (I think by "valid" you're referring to pure functional programming). What makes a function "pure" in functional programming is that its return value is only determined by its input values and nothing else. It also does not modify any external state or variables (referred to as "free variables" or global variables, meaning a variable that is not bound in the input parameters). What you're doing in `execute` can be expressed in a functional programming language trivially, for example Haskell:

```hs
execute :: Car -> Command -> (Car, String)
execute car cmd = let newCar = move car cmd in (newCar, reportPosition newCar)
```

2. If `move` had to report additional data, you could include it in the return type and it would remain pure. However, assuming "if the car crashed" is an error state, then typically this would be modeled by returning a sum type (`Maybe` or `Either` in Haskell). Take `Maybe` for example: `data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing`, if the car crashed you could return `Nothing` and if it didn't then return `Just position`, then anything using the `move` function can verify that it didn't return `Nothing`.
3. Why would you not be allowed to call `createCar` inside `move`? Neither `move` nor `createCar` are modifying any external state/variables, both are only using the inputs provided in their returns.

Re-iterating my comment in the main post, a lot of these things from Haskell that I mentioned above (e.g. `Maybe`) are available in libraries for JavaScript/TypeScript. For TypeScript in particular, there's https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts. It can be a little bit confusing sometimes, as usually there are many names that refer to the same concept. For instance, some libraries refer to `Maybe` as `Option`.